# html: демонстрация загрузчика пока загружается страница

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, оптимизация, loader

Приветствую

Сделал загрузчик, пока загружается страница сайта, как только все данные переданы клиенту, страница сформирована и т.д. загрузчик скрывается.

Есть одна проблема - на странице загружается много библиотек (`<script ... >`), и, как я понимаю, пока все, что находится до `<body>` не будет загружено, в `<body>` ничего выведено не будет, в том числе и мой загрузчик.

В результате получается, что часть времени (заметную) вначале экран браузера просто белый и только потом появляется загрузчик.

Вопрос, как это можно исправить?

Одно из решений возможно заключается в том, чтобы всю начинку  сформировать динамически с помощью javascript, тогда тело страницы будет сформировано сразу, потом начнёт выполняться javascript код.

Comment: async и defer вариант ?

Comment: <script src="js.js"></script>
</body> вставьте  script_ты  перед закрытием /body

Comment: @Максим Ленский, не понял

Comment: Почитайте [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)